# Understanding notation on Fulton Harris book "Representation theory, a first course"

Tags: representation-theory

I just want to confirm the meaning of $^t\rho(g^{-1})$ in this passage : is it well the adjoin map of $\rho(g^{-1})$ ? is it a standard notation ?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's the adjoint (i.e., the dual map). The notation is rather standard in France (which doesn't quite explain why Fulton/Harris are using it).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am kind of against this notation since it alludes to finite dimensional transpose, even the natural pairing is not defined in the book that I had to google it.

Comment: Fulton/Harris is infamous for being sloppy and incomplete at points.

Comment: thank you, speaking of France, can you recommend a good french book dealing with representation theory

Comment: Afraid I can't, but Sophie Morel has a set of notes ( https://web.math.princeton.edu/~smorel/rep_theory_notes.pdf ) that looks like it follows the French tradition.